# Retrieve Business Units and add to data extension SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs, sfmc-business-unit, wsproxy

I have the following SSJS function which uses WSProxy to return an array of all business units, however, when I test the script in a CloudPage, it returns an error.

I'm hoping someone can take a look at the prox.retrieve() i put together and let me know what I am missing.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.5");
try{

  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(),
    queryAllAccounts = true,
    objectType = "Account",
    cols = ["ID","Name"],
    data = prox.retrieve(objectType, cols, queryAllAccounts)
    fields = [];
    for (var i=0; i<data.Results.length; i++) {
        fields.push({
            ID: data.Results[i].ID,
            name: data.Results[i].Name
        });
    }
    var de = DataExtension.Init('BusinessUnitDetails');
    var result = de.Rows.Add(fields);        
    Write("Result: " + result + " rows added")      


 }
 catch (err) {
  Write("Error Message: " + Stringify(err.message) + Stringify(err.description));
 }
</script>
```

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: 500 Internal Server error

Comment: If I remove var from data and fields, it returns: "Error Message: "Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.""System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"" @Gortonington

Comment: Was missing filter in prox.retrieve
Its working now.

Comment: Can anyone help me with filter to be used